# scrapy still writes DEBUG message despite selecting INFO level

Tags: logging, scrapy

I'm trying to get rid of the `DEBUG` log messages when running scrapy unfortunately to no avail. I tried to put that in the spider init :

```
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='log.txt',
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)
```

But it still writes DEBUG messages. Then I tried to put `LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'` in the `setting.py` file but it still floods the log file with DEBUG messages.

Any idea how to get rid of the DEBUG messages ? It's fine if they are being printed in STDERR but just not in the log file.

Comment: How are you running your spider? do you see different behavior when using log file and using console output? can you share some logs?

Comment: @paultrmbrth I run it with `scrapy crawl name` basically changing the setting in `setting.py` has an effect on the `stderr` output as `DEBUG` level messages are not printed anymore in the console. However it still writes everything in the file log. So what I did is to remove the file output and use `2> file` to redirect stderr from bash.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this behavior. `LOG_LEVEL='INFO'` + `LOG_FILE='log.txt'` in my `settings.py` or on the cmd line for `scrapy crawl` does not print debug lines to the log file. Are you sure your settings are being read correctly? (you mention `setting.py`, it's usually `settings.py`, in case it was not a typo in your question). You should see something like `[scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'logfilelevel.spiders', ..., 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['logfilelevel.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'logfilelevel', 'LOG_FILE': 'log.txt'}` when the crawl starts.